# Multiple monitors - adjust sharpness (edit: Event name *BlueScreen*)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a 13" laptop that I want to connect to my new samsung smart station. Earlier today, it worked and the monitor were found by the windows7 control panel called "set up computer to multiple monitor". Then a screenshot would like like this [image]

But now, having plugged in and out the cables on my smart station, the "set up computer to multiple monitor" did not find my samsung screen. As a consequence, now I can see a *mirror* of my laptops screen, previously the laptop was blank. More importantly, the screen is blurry. Here is a screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywlkmxt6h5yusze/Screenshot%202014-05-06%2016.40.34.png As a side note, the mouse is not recognized by the samsung.

---

I also see now, if you compare the first and second screen shot, that the menu bar has changed. It's supposed to be black. I guess some software made it blue. Edit: no it's back to normal again, it was some intel sofware causing it.

**EDIT**
**I got the error message called blueScreen**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1053

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   1000009f
  BCP1: 0000000000000004
  BCP2: 0000000000000258
  BCP3: FFFFFA80066FC040
  BCP4: FFFFF80000B9C3D0
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\050614-4508-01.dmp 
  C:\Users\jl\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-3252106-0.sysdata.xml
```

link to those problem files are here

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/7113tsy2d2oiz1u/050614-4508-01-copiedfromme.dmp
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/ou974busi9yqimi/WER-3252106-0copiedfromme.sysdata.xml

I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dump, the driver `lan9500-x64-n620f.sys` (SMSC LAN9500 USB 2.0 to Ethernet 10/100) causes the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 0000000000000258, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: fffffa80066fc040, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: fffff80000b9c3d0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_PNP on Win7 and higher

Debugging Details:
------------------

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KiSwapContext
nt!KiCommitThreadWait
nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
ndis!NdisWaitEvent
lan9500_x64_n620f
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  lan9500-x64-n620f.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_4_lan9500_x64_n620f+114d6

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x9f_4_lan9500_x64_n620f+114d6

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lan9500-x64-n620f.sys
    Image name: lan9500-x64-n620f.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Oct 19 19:55:25 2012
```

Install the updated driver from [here](http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=OBJ-LAN95xx-WINDOWS) and look if it fixes it.

Comment: how do I find and updated version? googled *lan9500-x64-n620f.sys* but did not know where to go.

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/producttc.aspx?product=OBJ-LAN95xx-WINDOWS

Comment: thanks, I downloaded it. Now the screen works, but without the correct resolution (it has the same resolution as my 13" laptop). and the samsung screen still does not work as it should, see image https://www.dropbox.com/s/pr3pwxmn8d4heci/IMAG0012.jpg

Comment: don't select "duplicate", select "extend" when you press WIN+P

Comment: my final question (I think), how do I make it so that when I shut down my laptop, then the computer is still going strong and I can see whats on the projector?

Comment: I have tried here https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7z341vbnk44rml/Screenshot%202014-05-08%2022.35.04.png

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "strong" in this context.

Comment: (it's a super basic question.) that I am still able to use the computer. i.e. it does not shut down just because I close the lid. looked in the power setting but did not find it.