# BlueScreen error - slow shutdown and error message on login

Tags: windows-7

My computer is extremely slow to exit. This is an error message.

(see earlier question I had here [Multiple monitors - adjust sharpness (edit: Event name *BlueScreen*)](https://superuser.com/questions/750381/multiple-monitors-adjust-sharpness-edit-event-name-bluescreen/750632?noredirect=1#comment970561_750632)
.)

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1053

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   1000009f
  BCP1: 0000000000000004
  BCP2: 0000000000000258
  BCP3: FFFFFA800671D660
  BCP4: FFFFF80000B9C3D0
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1
```

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\050814-5319-01.dmp
  C:\Users\jl\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-16848-0.sysdata.xml

*The files can be found here*

- [wer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqnwxnrrmrpcnro/WER-16848-0.sysdata.xml)
- [dmp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/idd6kd6wgy4jmnx/050814-5319-01.dmp)

Comment: Does this happen while in safe mode?

Comment: The bug check code is `0x1000009f`, which has the same meaning as [bug check `0x9F`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE`). The issue seems to be related to the `lan9500-x64-n620f.sys` module, which is the **SMSC LAN9500 USB to Ethernet Adapter** driver. I'd have suggested updating it, but the file timestamp is October 30, 2013, which matches that of the latest one available on the [official website](http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=OBJ-LAN95xx-WINDOWS).

Comment: @Ramhound well, I shut the computer down and then it took a while. Then the computer entered safe mode. So it might be yes, might be no.

Comment: @and31415 is there anything I should do?

Comment: @user1603548 - You have to be certain. Does this BSOD happen while in Safe Mode. If it does not then the problem is caused by a driver. `BlueScreenView` can tell you which drivers were loaded at the time of the crash. Update your question with that information.  Simplest solution would be uninstall the `SMSC LAN9500` and delete the  driver